# Two Decimals in Python?

Tags: python, decimal

I'm trying to make this program which calculates the volume and surface area of a cylinder; I am currently coding the volume part of it. However, in the output screen, there are two decimals. It shows:

> The volume of the cylinder is193019.2896193019.2896cm³

Why are there two?

After that, I'm trying to make the program ask the user how many decimal places (d.p.) the user wants. How can I do this?

Here is the current code:

```
print("Welcome to the volume and surface area cylinder calculator powered by Python!")
response = input("To calculate the volume type in 'vol', to calculate the surface area, type in 'SA': ")
if response=="vol" or response =="SA":
    pass
else:
    print("Please enter a correct statement.")
    response = input("To calculate the volume type in 'vol', to calculate the surface area, type in 'SA': ")

if response=="vol":
    #Below splits 
    radius, height = [float(part) for part in input("What is the radius and height of the cylinder? (e.g. 32, 15): ").split(',')] 
    PI = 3.14159 #Making the constant PI
    volume = PI*radius*radius*height
    print("The volume of the cylinder is" + str(volume) + "{}cm\u00b3".format(volume))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are interpolating the value *twice*:

```
print("The volume of the cylinder is" + str(volume) + "{}cm\u00b3".format(volume))
```

Just once will do:

```
print("The volume of the cylinder is {}cm\u00b3".format(volume))
```

The nice thing about the `.format()` function is that you can tell it to format your number to a certain number of decimals:

```
print("The volume of the cylinder is {:.5f}cm\u00b3".format(volume))
```

where it'll use 5 decimals. That number can be parameterized too:

```
decimals = 5
print("The volume of the cylinder is {0:.{1}f}cm\u00b3".format(volume, decimals))
```

Demo:

```
>>> volume = 193019.2896
>>> decimals = 2
>>> print("The volume of the cylinder is {0:.{1}f}cm\u00b3".format(volume, decimals))
The volume of the cylinder is 193019.29cm³
>>> decimals = 3
>>> print("The volume of the cylinder is {0:.{1}f}cm\u00b3".format(volume, decimals))
The volume of the cylinder is 193019.290cm³
```

I'll leave using `input()` and `int()` to ask for an integer number of decimals from the user up to you.

Comment: As a sidenote, when putting a value inside a `print()` function, you don't need to explicitly call `str()` on it, the `print()` function does this automatically. (Well, it gets the object's `__str__` property, which is what `str()` calls). EDIT: Only when NOT using string concat inside the fn.

Comment: @gos1: not when using `+` to concatenate the values first.

Comment: This is what I get when I do too much Java and not enough Python, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about asking the user how many decimal he wants:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

decimals = int (input ('How many decimals? ') )
print ('{{:.{}f}}'.format (decimals).format (1 / 7) )
```

Comment: No need to go to that length; you can do this with *one* `.format()` call directly. See my answer.